# What is the time complexity of the second for loop in the following nested loop?

Tags: performance, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I'm trying to analyze the running time (Big-Oh) of some code fragments and the following one I am having trouble with:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<i*i; ++j) { 
         //random stuff here costs O(1)
    }
}
```

The first loop is O(n) but in the second loop, i*i throws me off. What is the time complexity for the second loop? Please don't list the overall time complexity as that would give away the whole answer. Just hints or advice or resources would be helpful!
Thank you!

Comment: so, for a given `i`, say i == 1, you get 1 iteration. for i == 2, you get 4 iterations. for i == 3 you get 9 iterations...

Answer (score 0):

Let analyze what `i*i` is at each step. First its 0, then 1, then 4, then 9 ...

So in general we are looking at

[image]

This is good news, there is a closed from for this summation, you can prove the correctness by induction as an exercise. Here I take it for granted that

[image: k=1∑n​kk=1∑n​k2k=1∑n​k3​=2n(n+1)​=6n(n+1)(2n+1)​=4n2(n+1)2​.​]

And if you're familiar with big-O it's easy to see how we conclude the above is O(n^3). Here is some more reading on some common summations that come  up a lot in CS, I recommend taking a look https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/